# Android Studio Designer Preview went Black after implementing Material Components library

Tags: android-studio

I am new in Android Development. In the latest version of Android Studio I want to use Material Components for my app. But after implementing its gradle script my Android Studio Designer Preview went black/blank. As you can see in screenshot below.

[image]

I have implemented the following line in my `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

After removing the material components library the preview looks as it should.
I have also tried to restart Android studio as well as my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I have used

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-rc01'
```

Now the issue has been fixed.